# Django Class-based View and URL configuration

Tags: python, django

I am trying to learn Django and I am stuck with Class-based views and URLconf. From what I understand I should see my test.html at `localhost/app1/test1/test/test.html`, but I get an error page not found. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

```
#~/project_folder/mysite/ulrs.py
urlpatterns = [
path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
path('app1/test1/', include("app1.urls")),
]

#~/project_folder/app1/urls.py
urlpatterns = [
path('test/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="test.html"), name="home"),
]

#~/project_folder/static/templates
test.html

#~/project_folder/mysite/settings.py
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [
        os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/templates'),
    ],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
...
}

STATIC_URL = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static/')
```

Comment: But test.html is your template name, not your path. Your path, as configured, is /app1/test1/test/.

Comment: It works and indeed was a silly thing... Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- Django html-templates are not supposed to be treated as *static files* and regular path for them is like `"app/templates/app"` (examine tutorial and demo-projects)
- template file names are not exposed to the end-user and do not partake  in url path, so
  this particular setup

  `path('app1/test1/', include("app1.urls")),
   path('test/', TemplateView.as_view(template_name="test.html"), name="home"),`

actually means: for rendering response on url `app1/test1/test/` request use `test.html` template. If you rename template filename to `"whatever-foo-bar-my-template.html"` url will not change.